# $n$-gons on grid with $1$ internal grid point

Tags: discrete-geometry

Investigating the triangle with $1$ internal point:

There are at least $5$ triangles:

[image: Triangle 1]
[image: Triangle 2]

EDITED:
According to comment adding the $3$-rd case:
[image: Triangle 3]

[image: Triangle 4]

[image: Triangle 5]

Is it known how many triangles and $n$-gons in general exist with $1$ internal point.

Comment: What about the triangle $(0,0), (1,0), (2,3)$?

Comment: Just have edited according to your comment. Thanks

Comment: What about the triangle $(0,0), (1,0), (2, 4)$? $(0,0), (3,0), (1,2)$?

Comment: Please take a look at edited question.

Comment: Is this infinite? Just trying to find some literature on this.

Comment: You can draw a line from the internal point to each of the 3 outside points .... there - you have three triangles. But I don't quite understand the question (especially about the n-gons)

Comment: Dear Josh the question is how many triangles with vertices on grid exist with 1 internal grid point. Is this finite? If yes the exact count.

Comment: And the same for 4-gons etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 3 is the last interesting $n$.

For $n=4$, consider the (possibly concave) quadrilateral $(0,0), (2,0), (1,2), (0,y)$ for arbitrary positive $y\ne 4$, which encloses only $(1,1)$.

Or this convex quadrilateral $(1,0), (x, 1), (-1,0), (-x, -1)$ for arbitrary $x$, which encloses only $(0,0)$.

Comment: Maybe one should add the condition that the polygon is convex in order to make the cases $n\geq4$ interesting again.

Comment: Yes this proves that for $n=4$ the solutions are infinite. Obviously the same is for $n>=5$. I think the next question is 2 internal point case.

Comment: And also are the cases listed for triangle cover all cases?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I have added a family of convex quadrilaterals that enclose only one lattice point.

Comment: Amazingly nice!