# Finite set of grid points inside of grid verticed $n$-gones

Tags: discrete-geometry

**Trying to prove:**

There is finite set of triangles with vertices on a grid enclosing any finite set of grid points. While there are infinite set of $n$-gones enclosing the same set for $n\ge4$. 
Some samples follow:
for 1 point:
[$n$-gons on grid with $1$ internal grid point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372596/n-gons-on-grid-with-1-internal-grid-point)

For 2 points the triangles are:

[image: Triangle1]
[image: Triangle2]
[image: Triangle3]

And may be few more.
There is a good sample of infinitness of enclosing 4-gones in comments of referenced question.